# Relevance of shared memory bank conflicts in Fermi and higher

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory, bank-conflict

From what I read in the CUDA documentation, shared memory bank conflicts are irrelevant on sm_20 and higher because values are broadcasted when they are requested simultaneously, preventing any sort of serialization delays.

The documentation:

> The shared memory hardware is improved on devices of compute
>   capability 2.x to support  multiple broadcast words and to generate
>   fewer bank conflicts for accesses of 8-bits, 16-bits,  64-bits, or
>   128-bits per thread (Section G.4.3).

Can someone confirm my assertion?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No they are not "irrelevant".

I believe your confusion may be arising from a common misconception with bank conflicts that "bank" is somehow equal to "location".  There is a relationship between bank and location, but it is not necessarily one of equality.

To take a simplified example, suppose we had 4 banks (and let's limit the discussion to 32-bit transactions, and naturally aligned 32 bit storage, e.g. `int` or `float`).  The relationship between banks and locations (`int` or `float` index "addresses") is as follows:

```
address:  bank:
       0      0 <-----------------------Thread 0
       1      1
       2      2     ------Thread 1
       3      3    /
       4      0 <---------Thread 2
       5      1
       6      2 
       7      3
       8      0 <-----------------------Thread 3
...
```

We see that addresses 1 and 5, for example, are in the same bank, but they are not the same location.

Bank conflicts (on any architecture) can arise whenever two or more threads in a warp are attempting to access data in the same *bank* as a result of a particular warp transaction (e.g. read from shared memory).

In the pre-fermi case, even if multiple threads read from the same *location* (i.e. address), this was a bank conflict, as those threads were reading from the same bank.

In the cc2.x or greater case, a *broadcast* mechanism was introduced.  This mechanism has *no effect* on the general case of bank conflicts, except for one specific case.  When multiple threads read from the *same location*, this is no longer a bank conflict, and all threads reading from that location will receive the data in a particular cycle without serialization.

However, under *any circumstances*, if multiple threads read from separate locations that are in the *same bank*, that is a bank conflict, under any current GPU architecture.

In the above picture, if Thread 0 reads from location/address 0, and Thread 3 reads from location/address 8 that will *always* be a bank conflict on any current architecture (given that this is a simplified example with only 4 banks).  If Thread 1 and Thread 2 both read from location/address 4, that is a bank conflict on pre-fermi but not on all fermi devices and beyond.

For a 32 bank arrangement, which is an actual bank configuration, the *bank* of any location in shared memory is given by the lower 5 bits of the index or offset to that location, regardless of whether that location happens to belong to a `int` or `float` array.

Comment: lower 5 bits of a "float" ?  i think you meant "the integer part of a float", maybe! :-) 
apart from that, i "presume" the lower 5 bits are the same mask used to determine the warp of a thread id. But i'm not sure.

Comment: the lower 5 bits of the `int` or `float` **offset**.  The referenced 5 bits are of the **offset to that location** whether it happens to be an `int` array or a `float` array, i.e. the array index, which is not a `float` quantity itself.  Reworded.